# Jooq to mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, jooq

I am trying to recreate a java program but I have stumbled upon a problem with a database. I only have jooq data and I do not know how to convert it into a mysql database. Does anyone know how you do this?

I have tried to read the jooq code but I wasn't able to recreate a DB out of it.

I apparently have to put some code here so i will put the *AsInDatabaseStrategy* here:

```
    package <classified>.jooq;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.jooq.util.DefaultGeneratorStrategy;
import org.jooq.util.Definition;

/**
 * It is recommended that you extend the DefaultGeneratorStrategy. Most of the
 * GeneratorStrategy API is already declared final. You only need to override any
 * of the following methods, for whatever generation behaviour you'd like to achieve
 * <p/>
 * Beware that most methods also receive a "Mode" object, to tell you whether a
 * TableDefinition is being rendered as a Table, Record, POJO, etc. Depending on
 * that information, you can add a suffix only for TableRecords, not for Tables
 */
public class AsInDatabaseStrategy extends DefaultGeneratorStrategy
{
    /**
     * Override this to specify what identifiers in Java should look like.
     * This will just take the identifier as defined in the database.
     */
    @Override
    public String getJavaIdentifier(Definition definition)
    {
        return definition.getOutputName();
    }

    /**
     * Override these to specify what a setter in Java should look like. Setters
     * are used in TableRecords, UDTRecords, and POJOs. This example will name
     * setters "set[NAME_IN_DATABASE]"
     */
    @Override
    public String getJavaSetterName(Definition definition, Mode mode)
    {
        return "set" + definition.getOutputName().substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + definition.getOutputName().substring(1);
    }

    /**
     * Just like setters...
     */
    @Override
    public String getJavaGetterName(Definition definition, Mode mode)
    {
        return "get" + definition.getOutputName().substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + definition.getOutputName().substring(1);
    }

    /**
     * Override this method to define what a Java method generated from a database
     * Definition should look like. This is used mostly for convenience methods
     * when calling stored procedures and functions. This example shows how to
     * set a prefix to a CamelCase version of your procedure
     */
    @Override
    public String getJavaMethodName(Definition definition, Mode mode)
    {
        return "call" + org.jooq.tools.StringUtils.toCamelCase(definition.getOutputName());
    }

    /**
     * Override this method to define how your Java classes and Java files should
     * be named. This example applies no custom setting and uses CamelCase versions
     * instead
     */
    @Override
    public String getJavaClassName(Definition definition, Mode mode)
    {
        if (mode == Mode.RECORD)
            return definition.getOutputName().substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + definition.getOutputName().substring(1) + "Record";
        else
            return definition.getOutputName().substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + definition.getOutputName().substring(1);
    }

    /**
     * Override this method to re-define the package names of your generated
     * artefacts.
     */
    @Override
    public String getJavaPackageName(Definition definition, Mode mode)
    {
        return super.getJavaPackageName(definition, mode);
    }

    /**
     * Override this method to define how Java members should be named. This is
     * used for POJOs and method arguments
     */
    @Override
    public String getJavaMemberName(Definition definition, Mode mode)
    {
        return definition.getOutputName();
    }

    /**
     * Override this method to define the base class for those artifacts that
     * allow for custom base classes
     */
    @Override
    public String getJavaClassExtends(Definition definition, Mode mode)
    {
        return Object.class.getName();
    }

    /**
     * Override this method to define the interfaces to be implemented by those
     * artefacts that allow for custom interface implementation
     */
    @Override
    public List<String> getJavaClassImplements(Definition definition, Mode mode)
    {
        return Arrays.asList(Serializable.class.getName(), Cloneable.class.getName());
    }

    /**
     * Override this method to define the suffix to apply to routines when
     * they are overloaded.
     * <p/>
     * Use this to resolve compile-time conflicts in generated source code, in
     * case you make heavy use of procedure overloading
     */
    @Override
    public String getOverloadSuffix(Definition definition, Mode mode, String overloadIndex)
    {
        return "_OverloadIndex_" + overloadIndex;
    }
```

Comment: As far as I can tell from reading the jOOQ website, it's an access wrapper for Java *for* SQL databases. It doesn't appear to store anything in its own right. Your data from the Java application should be stored in an SQL database somewhere, yes?

Comment: Problem is i do not have access to that database

Comment: As in the database is hosted by someone else? But you still have access to the data in your Java code? And is it possible for you to write new Java code in that application?

Comment: I kinda jacked the code and want to be able to get it to work but i have no access to the DB since it hosted locally according to the code

Comment: I don't understand. If the database is hosted locally then you have access to it. Please, what do you actually need help with?

Comment: Let me explain i jacked someone's code and i am trying to recreate it for personal use they have the database hosted locally so i can't connect to it to get the db format in the code i jacked was jooq data now the thing i need help with is how do i recreate a database with only jooq data

Comment: Are you looking to take all the Jooq code you have access to, like DAOs, Pojos, tables, and reverse engineer the Jooq DB from it?